# Why aren't text and images being displayed in NavigationView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a NavigationView that is supposed to display an image and some text in a ScrollView however the screen is just blank.

Here is the code:

```
NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {
                Color("HomeBG3")
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                
                
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
     
                    ForEach(MarketplaceModel.business_details_array) { items in
                        
                        VStack {
                            
                            GeometryReader { geo in
                                Image("ProductDefaultImage")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 1, height: 300)
                            }
                            Text("Test")
                        }
                    }

                }
                
                
            }
        }
        
        .navigationTitle(businessData.title)
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .onAppear(perform: {
            
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            let stringOne = defaults.string(forKey: "key")!
            
            self.MarketplaceModel.fetchBusinessDetails(id: business_id, key: stringOne)
            
        })
```

Any ideas on why the image and text are not appearing?

EDIT:
What's causing the image and text to overlap? When I remove the ZStack, they still overlap.
[image]

Comment: They are probably overlaying each other because of the `ZStack`. Wrap your `ForEach` in a `VStack`.

Comment: I thought this was the case and tried that but it doesn't seem to work. I can't figure out why

Comment: Then the issue is most probably not in the code you´ve shown. To start debugging you could use `let _ = print(....)` inside the `ForEach` and the `body`. Without more information this is not solvable. Also, the size of the images may be an issue. Try to add a frame to give a definitive size.

Comment: I have resolved this issue but now text is over the image. Even when I removed the ZStack and wrapped the image and text in a VStack, they overlapped. I updated the code and provided a screenshot. What is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Wrap the `ForEach` itself and not it´s items.... e.g.: `VStack{ ForEach(...`

Comment: When I did this I got the same results (the text is overlaying the image). I think it may have something to do with the Geometry Reader

Comment: Yeah, taking out Geometry Reader seemed to fix it.